# How do I show a simple_form input field depending on a previous form selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a simple_form field

```
<%= f.input :plan_type, collection: Plan::PLAN_TYPES %>
```

And another input_field that I have to show **only** if the selected option in the field above is X

I tried something like the following, but it show's the input field no matter what the selection in the other field is:

```
<% if f.object[:plan_type] != Plan::PLAN_TYPES.last %>
  <%= f.input :discount_amount, input_html: { min: 0 } %>
<% end %>
```

I need to solve this without any JS involved. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I need to solve this without any JS involved*. Good luck with that.

Comment: If you need the field to show/hide based on the user making changes in the form without submitting it ... you have to use JS.